# Set Column Width in C# (Interop.Excel) could be too larger

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop

I counldn't set the width with Interop.

My code is :

```
                    double kA = ((Excel.Range)st.Columns[1]).EntireColumn.Width;
                    double kB = ((Excel.Range)st.Columns[2]).EntireColumn.Width;
                    int KNA = Convert.ToInt32(kA + kB);
                    //((Excel.Range)st.Columns[1]).EntireColumn.ColumnWidth = kA + kB;

                    Console.WriteLine(KNA);
                    ((Excel.Range)st.Columns[1]).ColumnWidth = KNA;

                    Console.WriteLine(((Excel.Range)st.Columns[1]).EntireColumn.Width);
                    ((Excel.Range)st.Columns[2]).EntireColumn.Delete();
```

Both kA and kB is 59.25,and KNA is 118.But the actual  width of Column A is 801.75,and it couldn't be modified any way.
I use ((Excel.Range)st.Columns[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UaZsV.png)).ColumnWidth = KNA;
But the columnA  width couldn't be change.
What's wrong?

I tried to change the initial columnWidth of column A&B,and I got the different value of new column width but is still more larger than KNA,about 6.8 times each time.

Before run code:
[image]

After run code:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I use columnWith to get and set columnwidth,and It's OK.